# Command problems with giving potions minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command that gives Max Welfrice a custom potion. Here is the command I use:

```
/give @p potion 1 16389 {name:MaxWelfrice},{CustomPotionEffects:[1:{Id:7,Amplifier:1,Duration:0}]}
```

But it doesn't work! I'm a noob to this command thing so can anyone check it for me?

Comment: Do you want to give the potion to a player called `MaxWelfrice`, or do you want to give the nearest player a potion named `MaxWelrice`?

Comment: give the player named MaxWelfrice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/give MaxWelfrice potion 1 16389 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:1,Duration:0}]}
```

If you'd like to give a potion to a particular player, simply just enter their username. Instead of a selector and NBT tag with their username in it.

Comment: ok ths a lot both aytimothy and CommandFox! :)